# How to display list item gradually using css only?

Tags: css-animations

There's a list of items. The first item is always visible. Click it will make the remaining items display. I would like to make the remaining items display gradually. When closing, the items should close gradually as well.

Here's the codes I have so far. https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-tu-yyck5h?file=/src/styles.scss:82-110.

Thanks for your help in advance.